# Getting error while trying to update the data in flutter firebase - Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument: Instance of 'TextEditingController'

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to update a data. I got the values form another page by passing it, and the data is showing in the text field. But When I try to update the data is not updating. Can anyone tell what I am doing wrong here. I am getting an error as  `Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument: Instance of 'TextEditingController`

This is my complete coding

```
class updateAddress extends StatefulWidget {
final String firstName;
final String lastName;
final String region;
final String city;
final String address1;
final String address2;
final String primaryPhone;
final String secondaryPhone;

const updateAddress(
  {Key? key,
  required this.firstName,
  required this.lastName,
  required this.region,
  required this.city,
  required this.address1,
  required this.address2,
  required this.primaryPhone,
  required this.secondaryPhone})
  : super(key: key);

@override
_updateAddressState createState() => _updateAddressState();
}

class _updateAddressState extends State<updateAddress> {
late TextEditingController FirstName =
  TextEditingController(text: "${widget.firstName}");
late TextEditingController LastName =
  TextEditingController(text: "${widget.lastName}");
late TextEditingController Region =
  TextEditingController(text: "${widget.region}");
late TextEditingController City =
  TextEditingController(text: "${widget.city}");
late TextEditingController Address1 =
  TextEditingController(text: "${widget.address1}");
late TextEditingController Address2 =
  TextEditingController(text: "${widget.address2}");
 late TextEditingController PrimaryPhone =
  TextEditingController(text: "${widget.primaryPhone}");
late TextEditingController SecondaryPhone =
  TextEditingController(text: "${widget.secondaryPhone}");

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade100,
  appBar: AppBar(
    centerTitle: true,
    backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
    title: Text(
      'Update Address',
      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
    ),
    leading: IconButton(
      icon: Icon(
        Icons.arrow_back_ios,
        color: Colors.black,
      ),
      onPressed: () {
        Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/addressProfile');
      },
    ),
  ),
  body: Card(
    margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
    child: Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
        },
        child: ListView(
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: 30,
            ),
            TextFormField(
              maxLength: 20,
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 20),
              controller: FirstName,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: "First Name",
                floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always,
              ),
            ),
            TextFormField(
              maxLength: 20,
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 20),
              controller: LastName,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: "Last Name",
                floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always,
              ),
            ),
            TextFormField(
              maxLength: 15,
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 20),
              controller: Region,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: "Region",
                floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always,
              ),
            ),
            TextFormField(
              maxLength: 15,
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 20),
              controller: City,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: "City",
                floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always,
              ),
            ),
            TextFormField(
              maxLength: 20,
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 20),
              controller: Address1,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: "Address Line 1",
                floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always,
              ),
            ),
            TextFormField(
              maxLength: 20,
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 20),
              controller: Address2,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: "Address Line 2",
                floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always,
              ),
            ),
            TextFormField(
              keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
              inputFormatters: [
                FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,
              ],
              maxLength: 10,
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 20),
              controller: PrimaryPhone,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: "Primary Phone",
                floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always,
              ),
            ),
            TextFormField(
              keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
              inputFormatters: [
                FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,
              ],
              maxLength: 10,
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 20),
              controller: SecondaryPhone,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: "Secondary Phone",
                floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always,
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 30,
            ),
            Align(
              child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  FirebaseFirestore.instance
                      .collection('address')
                      .doc()
                      .update({
                    "firstName": FirstName,
                    "lastName": LastName,
                    "region": Region,
                    "city": City,
                    "address1": Address1,
                    "address2": Address2,
                    "primaryPhone": PrimaryPhone,
                    "secondaryPhone": SecondaryPhone
                  });
                  Fluttertoast.showToast(
                    msg: "Address updated Successfully",
                    toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
                    gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
                    textColor: Colors.black,
                    backgroundColor: Colors.green.shade400,
                  );
                },
                child: Text(
                  "Update Address",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 15, letterSpacing: 2, color: Colors.black),
                ),
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                    fixedSize: Size(250, 40),
                    primary: Colors.green.shade500,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      horizontal: 50,
                    ),
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10))),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
}
}
```

I need to pass the data in the textFormfild and view what the user have typed and then update user input. But In here user input is not updating. I am showing the passed value ${widget.value} in the EditTextController and an initial value.

I already tried adding as firstname.text

But that doesn't resolve the issue. Its showing the same error and `Some requested document was not found` error too. But The document is availavle in the database. I have added the documentid in the .doc() too. But no changes

Comment: What Id are you using as the DocumentId? Is it the firebase auto generated id or your own ID?

Comment: @Deepika I generated an id. Using nanoid plugin.

Comment: @Sinduja Did you check any of the answer added below?

Comment: @MidhunMP Yes I checked and edited the post

Comment: @Sinduja That is a different issue and nothing related to the first question you've added. You can see that in the error log itself. The new error is related to the document id or collection name you are passing.

Comment: So I don't see you are  passing that id to this class. Once you change the firebase id you need to use that as your document id. You need to pass the id you created also. Then you can use it in the doc. Like `doc(${widget.id})` .  This will solve your second error you mentioned.  Also sometimes you need to restart to make some changes work. Try restarting and both issues will be gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the firebase update function, you are passing the `TextEditingController`, instead of `String`.

Replace:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
   .collection('address')
   .doc()
   .update({
      "firstName": FirstName,
      "lastName": LastName,
      "region": Region,
      "city": City,
      "address1": Address1,
      "address2": Address2,
      "primaryPhone": PrimaryPhone,
      "secondaryPhone": SecondaryPhone
   });
```

With:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
   .collection('address')
   .doc()
   .update({
      "firstName": FirstName.text,
      "lastName": LastName.text,
      "region": Region.text,
      "city": City.text,
      "address1": Address1.text,
      "address2": Address2.text,
      "primaryPhone": PrimaryPhone.text,
      "secondaryPhone": SecondaryPhone.text
   });
```

Check the [TextEditingController](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/TextEditingController-class.html) documentation for more details

Answer (score 1):

You're currently passing an object of `TextEditingController` instead of the `text` in `String` form.

To get the text from a `TextEditingController` use the `text` property like so:

```
 FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('address')
      .doc()
      .update({
      "firstName": FirstName.text,
      "lastName": LastName.text,
      "region": Region.text,
      "city": City.text,
      "address1": Address1.text,
      "address2": Address2.text,
      "primaryPhone": PrimaryPhone.text,
      "secondaryPhone": SecondaryPhone.text
});
```